How to use ssh x11 forwarding on Windows?
I am running XServer by VcXsrv on Windows. Here is my VcXsrv configuration, and I believe it should be listening on :0.0, which is port :6000.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XLaunch WindowMode="MultiWindow" ClientMode="NoClient" LocalClient="False" Display="-1" LocalProgram="xcalc" RemoteProgram="xterm" RemotePassword="" PrivateKey="" RemoteHost="" RemoteUser="" XDMCPHost="" XDMCPBroadcast="False" XDMCPIndirect="False" Clipboard="True" ClipboardPrimary="True"
ExtraParams="" Wgl= "True DisableAC= "True"" XDMCPTerminate= "False"/>

My Linux server has xauth installed and SSH's x11 forwarding enabled. Here is a part of the sshd_config configuration on my Linux server:
AddressFamily inet
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes

If I understand correctly, when I run ssh -X debian@my.linux.server in Windows Powershell, I should see:

ssh listening on server's 127.0.0.1:6010
server's DISPLAY environment variable is set to localhost:10.0
Running gedit on server should trigger opening a window in VcXsrv on Windows

However, none of these are happening as expected. In the output of ssh -vvvv, I see this log:
debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set

Initially, I thought that the Linux Server did not have DISPLAY set up properly, but no matter how I modify it, it keeps prompting 'DISPLAY not set'. So, I tried configuring the environment variable in Windows Powershell:
$env:DISPLAY = "localhost:0"

Interestingly, now it no longer prompts 'DISPLAY not set', but still cannot open X11 forwarding.
debug1: No xauth program.
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed:xauth key data not generated 

Question
1.What am I missing? Do I need to install xauth on Windows as well? If so, how can it be installed?
2.What is the purpose of setting DISPLAY in Windows Powershell? Is it used to specify which XServer to forward X traffic to?
Version

Windows: Window 10 Enterprise 20H2 19042.1237
LinuxServer: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 5.10.0-28-amd64


What version of Windows? What version of the WSL kernel do you have installed? Do you have WSLg enabled?

@Ramhound Windows version has been updated, but I am not using WSL and WSLg. I use Powershell to run the default installed ssh.

Both server and client need xauth if you want untrusted (“secure”) X11 forwarding.

try to use -Y option insted -X:
ssh -Y debian@my.linux.server

looking at the man page " Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY  extension controls." which might help, but it would be good to say why this helps. The manpage also hints that this is the default on debian

Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation why it does so.
